# Splicing properties from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a utility (jquery, lodash, etc) that extracts properties from an object to another object and then deletes them from the original object? Similar to Array's splice?

```
obj1 = {color:"red", age:"23", name:"cindy"}
obj2 = extract(obj1, ["color","name"])
```

result:

```
obj1 is { age:23 }
obj2 is {color:"red", name:"cindy"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function for it, which iterates the keys and returns a new objectc and deletes the keys from the source object.

```js
function extract(object, keys) {
    return keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        o[k] = object[k];
        delete object[k];
        return o;
    }, {});
}

var obj1 = { color: "red", age: "23", name:"cindy" },
    obj2 = extract(obj1, ["color","name"]);
    
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use underscore's _.object() method to create a quick custom `extract` fn:

```
function extract(properties, object) {
  return _.object(properties, properties.map(prop => object[prop]));
}
```

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/293e0a311743539d5f2cb6f66225f4d8)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how custom `extract` function may be defined:

```js
function extract(o, keys) {
    var newObj = {};
    keys.forEach(function(k){
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {  // check if a key exists in `source` object 
            newObj[k] = o[k];
            delete o[k];     // removing property from `source` object
        }
    });

    return newObj;
}

var obj1 = {color:"red", age:"23", name:"cindy"},
    obj2 = extract(obj1, ["color","name"]);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```